# quiero enviar 2 valores de un input por ajax

Tags: php, ajax

No pasan mis valores a `componentes/tablaj.php`. Allí quiero usarlos para crear un filtro y que me busque solo los valores iguales en mi bd.

Estoy esta hecho en un tabla dinámica con `bootstrap`.

Si alguien me puede ayudar estaria muy agradecido llevo 1 semana buscandole la solución y no la encuentro.

```
<body style="background-color: beige;">
    <br><br><br>
    <center>
        <form action=preguntaweb.php method="POST" id="form">
            <table border="0">
                <tr class="Descripcion">
                    <td>Municipio:</td>
                    <td><input list="listaMunicipio" placeholder="Municipio" id="tuform" required="required" name="Municipio"/><datalist id="listaMunicipio">
                        <option value="25 de Mayo"/>
                        <option value="9 de Julio"/>
                        <option value="Adolfo Alsina"/>
                        <option value="Adolfo Gonzales Chaves"/>
                        <option value="Alberti"/>
                        <option value="Almirante Brown"/>
                        <option value="Arrecifes"/>
                        <option value="Avellaneda"/>
                        <option value="Ayacucho"/>
                        <option value="Azul"/>
                        <option value="Bahia Blanca"/>
                        <option value="Villa Gesell"/>
                        <option value="Villarino"/>
                        <option value="Zarate"/>
                    </datalist>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="Descripcion">
                <td>Codigo Municipio:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtCodMun"  id="txtCodMun" minlength= "5"maxlength="5" size="9" required="required" /></td>
                <tr class="Descripcion">
                    <td>Año: </td>

                    <td><input type="text" name="txtAño" id="txtAño" minlength="4 "maxlength="4" size="4" required="required"/></td>
                </tr>

            </center>
        </table>   <br>
        <input type="submit" name="btnLlamar" id="btnLlamar" value="Cargar Municipio"/>
        <input type="button" name="btnLlamar" id="btnLla" value="Cargar Municipio"/>
        <br><br>
    </form>

    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['txtCodMun'])|| isset($_POST['txtAño'])){
        $ente=$_POST['txtCodMun'];
        $año=$_POST['txtAño'];
        $enteaño=$ente.$año;
        $sql= "SELECT * from tablero where enteano =".$enteaño;
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        $fila=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            echo "<h2>" .$_POST['Municipio']." año ".$_POST['txtAño']."</h2>";

            ?>
            <br><br>


            <center>
                <form action=Eleccion.php method="POST">
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr class="Descripcion">
                         <td>Municipio:</td>
                         <td><input list="listaMunicipio2" required="required" name="Municipio2" value="<?php echo $fila['municipio'];?>"/><datalist id="listaMunicipio2">
                           <option value="25 de Mayo"/>
                           <option value="9 de Julio"/>
                           <option value="Adolfo Alsina"/>
                           <option value="Adolfo Gonzales Chaves"/>
                           <option value="Alberti"/>
                           <option value="Almirante Brown"/>
                           <option value="Arrecifes"/>
                           <option value="Avellaneda"/>
                           <option value="Ayacucho"/>
                           <option value="Azul"/>
                           <option value="Bahia Blanca"/>
                           <option value="Villa Gesell"/>
                           <option value="Villarino"/>
                           <option value="Zarate"/>
                       </datalist>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="Descripcion">
                <td>Codigo Municipio:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtCodMun"  minlength= "10"maxlength="10" size="9" required="required" value="<?php echo $fila['codmuni'];?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="Descripcion">
                <td>Año: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtAño"  minlength="4 "maxlength="4" size="4" required="required" value="<?php echo $fila['ano'];?>"/></td>

            </table>    <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="btnGuardar" value="Guardar Cambios"/>
        </form>
    </center>

    <!-- TABLA JUICIOS-->
    <div class="container">
        <div id="tablaj"></div>

    </div>

    <!-- Modal para registros nuevos -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="modalNuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agrega Nuevo Juicio</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label>Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="nombre" class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Monto</label>
            <input type="number" name="" id="monto" class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Actora/Demandada</label><center>A</center>
            <input type="radio" name="aa" id="jad"  class="form-control input-sm" value="Actora" /><center>D</center><input type="radio" name="aa" id="jad1" class="form-control input-sm"  value="Demandada" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="gnuevo">
                Agregar
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Modal para edicion de datos -->

<div class="modal fade" id="modalEdicion" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Editar Juicio</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" hidden="" id="idj" name="">
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="nombreu" class="form-control input-sm">
        <label>Monto</label>
        <input type="number" name="" id="montou" class="form-control input-sm">
        <label>Actora/Demandada</label><center>A</center>
        <input type="radio" name="aa2" id="jadu"  class="form-control input-sm" value="Actora" /><center>D</center><input type="radio" name="aa2" id="jadu1" class="form-control input-sm"  value="Demandada" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" id="actualizadatos">Actualizar</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php
}else {
    require_once "php/conexion.php";
    $conexion=conexion();
    $ente=$_POST['txtCodMun'];
    $año=$_POST['txtAño'];
    $enteaño=$ente.$año;
    $muni=$_POST['Municipio'];

    echo $ente;
    echo $año;
    echo $muni;
    echo $enteaño;




    $sql="INSERT into tablero (enteano, municipio, codmuni, ano)
    values('$enteaño','$muni','$ente','$año')";
?>
//igual que arriba 
<?php
}
};
?>
</body>
</html>


<!-- JUICIOS -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tablaj').load('componentes/tablaj.php');

    });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#gnuevo').click(function(){
            nombre=$('#nombre').val();
            monto=$('#monto').val();
            jad=$('input:radio[name=aa]:checked').val()
            agregardatos(nombre,monto,jad);
        });
    });


    $('#actualizadatos').click(function(){

      actualizaDatos();
  });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#btnLlamar').click(function( event ){
         event.preventDefault();
            var ente=$('#txtCodMun').val();
            var año=$('#txtAño').val(); 
            console.log(ente);
            console.log(año);
//envio a tablaj.php
       $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"componentes/tablaj.php",
            data:'ente=' + ente +'&año='+ año,
            success:function(){
                alert("se envio con exito");
            }
        });

});
</script>
```

Comment: la solucion fue pasar las variables por el directorio (modo de envio GET) de la siguiente manera
<!-- JUICIOS -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tablaj').load('componentes/tablaj.php?ente=ente&anio=anio');

    });

</script>

Answer (score 1):

En primera no te hace nada la función click porque no existe ese ID, necesitas agregarlo en tu etiqueta, así mismo los valores que intentas obtener de tus input no tienen ID, por eso no hace nada te recomiendo siempre utilices la consola, para ver si tienes errores con el JS, utiliza preventDefault(); para que ese input submit no te lleve a otra página.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#btnLlamar').click(function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
                    var ente=$('#txtCodMun').val();
                    var año=$('#txtAño').val(); 
                    console.log(ente);
                    console.log(año);
        //envio a tablaj.php
               $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"componentes/tablaj.php",
                    data:'ente=' + ente +'&año='+ año,
                    success:function(){
                        alert("se envio con exito");
                    }
                });
    
        });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--esta es la carga de los datos-->    
    <body>
    <html>
        <form action="testp1.php" method="POST" id="form">
          <table border="0">
             <tr class="Descripcion">
    <!--valor del primer input-->
             <td>Codigo Municipio:</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="txtCodMun" id="txtCodMun"></td>
        <!--valor del segundo input-->
             <tr class="Descripcion">
             <td>Año: </td>
             <td><input type="text" name="txtAño" id="txtAño"></td>
             </tr>
             </table><br>
             <!--boton al que llamo en ajax-->
             <input type="submit" name="btnLlamar" id="btnLlamar" value="Cargar Municipio">
             <br><br>
              </form>
              </html>
              </body>
```

Comment: creo que el event.preventDefault no es encesario porque me redirecciona a la misma pagina, todo esto esta programado en testp1.php, corregime si estoy equivocado porfavor :) todos los dias se aprende algo nuevo, y otra consulta para que sirve el console.log?

Comment: La función del AJAX es para recargar una cierta parte de tu página y no recargarla toda, no tendría sentido entonces utilizarlo si la vas a recargar toda solo para hacer una consulta a tu base de datos, por eso se utiliza el preventDefault();, console.log() es una forma de enviar datos a la consola del navegador, se puede utilizar por ejemplo para saber si estás entrando a una función y si esa función obtiene los valores de tales etiquetas, si no las obtiene te mandará un mensaje de error, de que esta indefinidam y demás errores, puedes hacer uso de ella oprimiendo f12 en tu navegador.

Comment: con tu codigo tal cual esta me sale el alert de "se envio con exito", pero no hace nada en la tabla que se encuentra abajo  creo que es por el event.preventDefault(); y si lo saco no sale el alert "se envio con exito"

Comment: puede ser que este faltando alguna linea de codigo en el function?, porque al <form id="form"> le pusimos un id pero ahora mirando el codigo no lo estamos llamando en ningun lado

Comment: Cuál tabla, sólo veo una donde están tus inputs, agrega el HTML completo.

Comment: ya edite la publicacion y lo subi casi completo,omiti la segunda parte del if ya que es casi igual a la de arriba y no me dejaba pegar tanto codigo

Comment: En tu PHP `componentes/tablaj.php` estas tomando el valor de $POST['ente'] y $_POST['año'] ?

Comment: <?php $dos= $_POST['ente']; echo $dos; $uno=$_POST['año']; echo $uno; ?> los tomo asi pero salen de la siguiente manera Undefined index: ente, del codigo que pases solo saque el .preventDefault ya que con el no aparecie la tabla ybasicamente no hacia nada

Comment: Cambia esta parte `data:'ente=' + ente +'&año='+ año,` por `data:{ente: ente, año: año}` y dime el resultado.

Comment: ahora los valores aparecen en el console(antes no lo hacia) pero sigue sin hacer nada en la tabla

Comment: Pues deberías checar tu código, tienes un revolvedero, si dices que necesitas recargar la página para que funcione tu tabla, ya que lo estás validando con PHP no te va a funcionar el AJAX, porque no se tiene que recargar apretando el botón submit, si vas a hacer selects o inserts en la misma página es necesario recargarla, por qué no mejor todo lo haces con AJAX, deberías plantearte mejor tu código, si en una misma página lo vas a hacer con PHP o con JS-AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

en el request que envias debererias enviar los datos del formulario de la siguiente manera

```
<script>
$('#btnLlamar').click(function(e){
    e.preventDeafault();
    var data = jQuery("#tuform").serializeArray()
    var request = jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'componentes/tablaj.php',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST'
            });

    request.done(function (response) {
        if (!response.status) {
            console.log(new Error(response.message));
        } else {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log(new Error(textStatus));
    });
</script>
```

En el HTML, en el formulario habria que agregar el id del form

```
<form action=testp1.php method="POST" id="tuform">
```

La data del form llegara a tu controlador con el nombre de tus inputs, osea `txtCodMun` y `txtAño`

Saludos,

Comment: lo cambie tan cual me dijiste pero hay algo que no entendi, a mi tablaj.php los datos los tengo que tomar asi <?php $ente=$_POST['txtCodmuni'];?> y use un echo$ente para ver si llegaban y no aparece nada en pantalla dice que estan sin definir. y otra consulta tengo entendido que el preventDeafault es para evitar que me redireccione no?, pero en mi caso no seria un problema ya que el btnLlamar redirecciona a la misma pagina, osea todo este codigo esta hecho en tablap1.php

Comment: En el controlador o en PHP deberias esperar por POST las variables `txtCodMun` y `txtAño` o al menos eso tiene definido como nombre de los campos en tu tabla que publicaste. Sobre el e.preventDeafault() es para que no se envie el formulario a la direccion que le indicaste en el `action` del form sino que lo envíe por AJAX, que es eso lo que buscas de acuerdo a la pregunta.

Comment: <?php
     $ente= $_POST['txtCodMun'];
    echo $ente;
?> lo recibi de la siguiente manera en mi tablaj.php y me sale en pantalla Undefined index: txtCodMun:(. tendria que usar alguna function para recibirla antes de hacer algo?

Comment: Has una prueba, cambia el tipo submit del boton enviar y cambialo por button `<input type="button" name="btnLlamar" id="btnLlamar" value="Cargar Municipio">` me avisas

Comment: si lo hago button no hace absolutamente nada :(

Comment: el codigo que envie esta dentro de `$(document).ready(function(){//codigo});` verdad?

Comment: sisi esta dentro del   $(document).ready(function(){]; pero no funciona en ninguna ni con button ni con submit